# I am facing a issue while authenticating user using oauth2 authentication for Office365

Tags: c#

I am facing a issue while authenticating user using oauth2 authentication for Office365. Using the below code

```
var cac = new ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate("AppID", new 
X509Certificate2());
AuthenticationResult  authenticationResult12 = 
authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serverName, cac).Result;


ExchangeService exchangeService = new 
ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
exchangeService.Url = new Uri(serverName + "EWS/Exchange.asmx");
exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
exchangeService.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
exchangeService.Credentials = new 
OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult12.AccessToken);
exchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new FolderView(10));
```

i am getting the token and also able to create service using EWS(ExchangeService ) but while fetching the root folder using the EWS service it gives an exception as "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

And Using the Below

```
var userId = new
```

ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier(UserID,UserIdentifierType.OptionalDisplayableId);

```
string clientSecret = "Client Secret key";

AuthenticationResult result1 = 
authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serverName, clientID, clientAppUri, 
new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always),userId, clientSecret).Result;
```

I am getting "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'." Exception.

I want to authenticate user account account of office Using ExchangeService
by oauth2 authentication.
Can anyone help me for this.
thank you

Comment: did you add auth redirect ural in your app registration in 365?